# Reverting git commits

Tags: git

I have a git repository setup and I have made several commits from my local branch and pushed these changes onto the master branch. I realised that this changes need to be reverted.

First question is, could I recover the project to the version that works.
If so how would I go about doing this either from source tree or terminal.

Lastly what are the implications or risk of undoing changes. Is there a chance this project could be lost forever. I really I am beginner with git so I am totally out of my depth.

Comment: BTW I suspect you were downvoted because there are likely many duplicates of this question on Stack Overflow already.

Answer (score 1):

You may find this flowchart useful:

http://justinhileman.info/article/git-pretty/

The key point is this. Has anyone else got the erroneous commit on their machine? If so, then you should look at `git revert`. If not, they you may like to use `git rebase -i` to interactively remove a commit from your history before `git push --force` to get the content back onto your remote.

There really is no substitute for hands on experience. I suggest you create a git repository in a new folder and experiment with these scenarios there. Good luck!